# How to get the mime type of a file from the command line?

Tags: command-line, files, mime-type

I'm trying to get the mime type of a file from the command line as a printed string (eg. `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet`).

I looked up how to do this and found the `xdg-mime` command.

From reading the man page (`man xdg-mime`), it seems I should run `xdg-mime query filetype FILE`. However, when I run this with any file it prints nothing and exits.

Is there a way to fix this? An alternative command?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Use `file --mime-type -b filename`

Look at `file --help` for more tips.

Answer (score 5):

The [great answer on this page](https://askubuntu.com/a/3397/4804) can be put in a function or script like so:

#### Example

```
$ mime_type.sh /etc/passwd  
text/plain
```

#### mime_type.sh

```
function mime_type()
{
  file --mime-type -b $*
}

mime_type $*
```

Answer (score 5):

```
mimetype /path/to/file
```

Tested in 18.04

Comment: `mimetype` works in 14.04 and above.

Comment: Also only detects the mimetype based on the file extension it seems

Comment: Works in 20.04 *but* it's like a million times slower than file --mime-type

Answer (score 4):

`xdg-mime` and file query different databases (`xdg-mime` is more comprehensive). See [Why the difference between the results with "file --mime-type" and "xdg-mime query filetype"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844864/why-the-difference-between-the-results-with-file-mime-type-and-xdg-mime-que) for more discussion.

`xdg-mime` does not work correctly from a non-desktop session (e.g. if you're SSH'd into a machine).