# Locate files matching mimetype in a directory recursively via command line

Tags: command-line, search

I wish to get a list of all files in a project folder [recursively] that are image files.
Unfortunately Google was unable to help me here.

If possible, the use of current system's mimetypes is preferred, eg all files that have a mime matching the glob `image/*`; so that any example could be easily extended for `video/*`, etc.

Additionally, commands that don't need to do expensive operations on every file in the entire directory are preferred as I might be trying to use this on some pretty huge volumes.

---

Note: A potential work around I have considered is fetching the list of file extensions from the mimetypes data and doing a `find` for these extensions, this is however less preferred due to the file extensions of the target files I'm wanting to locate may be missing, double loaded, etc.

---

Edit: Searching for files by extension, which I consider pretty trivial and not exactly what I'm looking for; I've edited the title to reflect that I'm looking specifically for mimetype based results.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are on 14.04 (using python3), the small script below lists your files recursively in given directory. It identifies the file's mimetype by the `file` command, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/3397/72216)

```
file --mime-type -b filename
```

additionally, you can extend the script by adding a command by using `shutil` (e.g. `.move / .copy`) at the same level as the `print` command.

**Adding mimetypes**

For a combined search, you can add (or remove) mimetypes to search for, by adding them to the `filetypes` -tuple.

**The script**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import subprocess

source_dir = "/path/to/directory"
filetypes = ("image", "video")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
    for name in files:
        file = root+"/"+name
        ftype = subprocess.check_output(['file', '--mime-type', '-b', file]).decode('utf-8').strip()
        if ftype.split("/")[0] in filetypes:
            print(file)
```

**How to use it**

Copy the script into an empty file, set the directory to list (`sourcedir`) and the mimtype(s) to look for (`filetypes`), save it as `list_files.py` and run it by the command:

```
python3 /path/to/list_files.py
```

Comment: Why use `file` if there's Python library to do it? http://stackoverflow.com/q/14412211

Comment: @muru I tried that, also https://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html, but got quite a few exceptions on a large directory I tested it on. Using `file` turned out to be pretty water-tight.

Comment: @muru: `mimetypes` doesn't look at the content (only the filename extension). You might mean [`imghdr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html) or [`python-magic` instead](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) e.g., `for curpath, _, files in os.walk(os.curdir):          
     for path in (os.path.join(curpath, name) for name in files):                                
         if re.match('image|video', magic.from_file(path, mime=True)):                           
             print(path)`

Answer (score 1):

I am not good in scripting but still this can find all files recursively and display it which are of image type using mimetype of files  .

```
 find . -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d'' f; do 
    file -ib $f | grep "^image/" && echo $f; 
 done
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be close:

```
find . -type f -exec mimetype {} + | awk -F': +' '{ if ($2 ~ /^image\//) print $1 }'
```

The regex being matched in the awk expression can be easily extended.