# Media Scanner Script

Tags: bash, scripts, filesystem, search, media

I am a beginner with Bash scripting.  I have recently been working on a script to harden Ubuntu computers for a school project.  Everything is going well, except that the students are not allowed to use any media files(.mp3, .mov, etc), and I am not sure how to do that. What command(s) would I use? grep? I have been researching this for a couple hours now with no luck.  It doesn't have to be long. All I need is an example and I can copy it for different extensions. I need it to be able to do the following:

- Find media files
- Send file paths to a text file
- notify a number of media files found

For example, I am looking for it to output something like this:

`Searching for media files...
5 media files found! Details can be found in 'media.txt'`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try this: `find /home -type f -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*(mp3|wma|mpg|mov)$'`. That ought to get you started. Combine with `wc -l` to see the number of files.

Answer (score 1):

To find files of a certain type, I wouldn't search for the file extension. I'd rather scan files for their MIME type using a combination of `find` and `file`. This output can then be `grep`ed for the desired mimetypesm e.g. `audio/*` and `video/*`.

I've created a small script to do so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#Don't know whether you want to do so, but this deletes a existing media.txt
rm media.txt
#Find files of desired MIME types and store them in $list
list=$(find | file -if - | grep -P "(audio/.*?;)|(video/.*?;)")
n=0
#Iterate over each line in the list (one file per line)
while read -r line; do
    #Append the filename to media.txt
    echo "$line" | cut -f1 >> media.txt
    #Increase file counter
    n=$(($n+1))
done <<< "$list"
#Output the result
echo "$n media files found! Saved to media.txt"
```

Note that I use full RegExp with grep. To add some MIME types, build them the same way as I did with the two already included: `(type/enc;)` and add them with a RegExp OR (`|`).

PS: As is, the script operates in the current directory. If you want to make it more flexible, add a `$1` between `find` and the following pipe. Now run the script and give the path to search as argument.

Comment: I just ran this code, and it said that there were 1093 files.  It turned out that they were not all files... any ideas?

Comment: Did you search in the correct directory? What files aren't found?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a more verbose option (python) that looks for mimetype(s) using the `file` command. It is an edited/rewritten version of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/523565/72216), made fit for your purpose.

#### What it does

*When files are found*
it returns a message (in the terminal):

```
checking for filetypes: image, video, audio...
4 media files found. See for details:  /home/jacob/Bureaublad/found.txt
```

while a text file is written to the directory/name you defined in the head section of the script

or, *if nothing is found*:

```
checking for filetypes: image, video, audio...
no files found
```

#### How to use

Copy the script below into an empty file, edit the three lines in the head section of the script:

```
source_dir = "/path/to/directory"
filetypes = ("image", "video", "audio") # you might want to leave this line as it is, used by the file command
report = "/path/to/report.txt"
```

save it as `find_media.py`, and run it in a terminal window by the command:

```
python3 /path/to/find_media.py
```

#### The script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import subprocess
# ---
source_dir = "/path/to/directory"
filetypes = ("image", "video", "audio")
report = "/path/to/report.txt"
# ---
print("checking for filetypes: "+(", ").join(filetypes)+"."*3)
found = []

def look_for():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
        for name in files:
            file = root+"/"+name
            ftype = subprocess.check_output(
                ['file', '--mime-type', '-b', file]
                ).decode('utf-8').strip()
            if ftype.split("/")[0] in filetypes:
                found.append(file)
    found_files = len(found)
    if found_files != 0:
        print(str(found_files), "media files found. See for details: ", report)
        with open(report, "wt") as out:
            for item in found:
                out.write(item+"\n")
    else:
        print("no files found")

look_for()
```