# Why the difference between the results with "file --mime-type" and "xdg-mime query filetype"?

Tags: mime-type

I am trying to find the mime-type of a file. I used either 'file --mime-type' or 'xdg-mime', but get different answers? I am not sure to understand?

```
$ file --mime-type -b gePlugin.kmz 
  application/zip
$ xdg-mime query filetype gePlugin.kmz 
  application/vnd.google-earth.kmz
```

Why do I have different answers? Which one should I rely on?

Why is there a difference?

Thanks!

Comment: Related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/7517/what-is-the-relationship-between-mime-types-and-file-extensions?rq=1

Comment: FWIW in your kmz example neither is wrong, the xdg-mime is just giving more information about a program that can use that data. It's zipped application data, as file says; but the specific application data can be used by Google Earth as xdg-mime says. They're directed towards different purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[@jdpipe appears to be correct](https://askubuntu.com/a/1050567/567307) regarding the behavior of `xdg-mime` and `file`. There is another utility `mimetype` that behaves similarly to `xdg-mime`.

As far as which utility to "trust", **it's usually fine to just use `mimetype` or `xdg-mime`.** However, **if you are concerned that a file may have the wrong extension, use `file`** because it examines the contents of the file before reporting its type. For example, if a `png` is renamed as `jpg`, `file` correctly reports "image/png", but `xdg-mime` and `mimetype` both *incorrectly* report "image/jpeg".

As [noted by @db429](https://askubuntu.com/a/844878/567307), it appears both utilities are correct for the `kmz` file you cite. Google Earth creates `kmz` files, which are also renamed `zip` files. What you want to do with the information determines which application to use. If you want to extract the contents, then `file` tells you to go ahead and use `unzip`. If you want to view and use the information as originally intended, use Google Earth or another program capable of using `kmz` files.

Regarding the `iso` file, I do not know why `xdg-mime` is telling you `model/x.stl-binary`. On my computer, it reports `application/x-cd-image`. Also, using `file` without the `--mime-type` flag reports additional information that confirms it is some type of disk image. Perhaps it would be helpful to update the mime database:

```
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

Comment: There is no one-to-one relation between extensions and MIME types (AKA [Internet Media Type](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)). For eg .iso is also used for [ISO 2709](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_2709), a file format very common for library bibliographic records.

Comment: Most probably the mime database got corrupted at some point in my case.

Comment: @cipricus Did `update-mime-database` fix it?

Comment: @xiota - for extraneous reasons I have reinstalled the system where that happened, but I hope I'll be able to remember your advice next time.:)

Comment: @cipricus Hope there is no next time 

Comment: `xdg-mime` is reporting `iso` files as `model/x.stl-binary` due to [a bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106330) in the `shared-mime-info` package.  This bug has been fixed upstream, but the fix has not yet been applied to Kubuntu 18.04.  I was able to fix my own installation by removing the `magic` stanza indicated in the [bugfix patch](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xdg/shared-mime-info/commit/?id=7c7f84e2a77f4142cf77ebdf239deaa14c842f9c) from the file `/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml`, then regenerating the mime cache using the command shown in this answer.

Comment: There is no definitive answer. If extensions are wrong, `xdg-mime`s output may be useless. If magic numbers are wrong, `file`s output may be useless. Suggesting that `file` is more trustworthy, is not helpful. I have e.g. a lot of plain-text files with different extensions, and `file` is absolute garbage at diagnosing which type and program is associated with a certain file.

Answer (score 5):

The `xdg-mime` utility from `xdg-utils` is a more comprehensive program that takes into account your desktop environment (GNOME and relatives, or KDE). In some cases it makes a call to the `file` utility, but in other cases it looks up the mimetype database for your particular system.

The `file` utility, as far as I can tell, only looks *inside* your file, it doesn't look at the filename. Hence the `.kmz` file, is recognised as a zip file. `file` makes use of 'magic numbers' which are associated with particular file types, eg the magic string `P5` at the start of a file is associated with PGM images from the Netpbm library.

The mimetype database knows about higher-level filetypes, as identified using filename extensions, and can be user-customised. When new programs are installed, the mimetype database is extended and will give answers that might not have been given before certain software was installed. To my knowledge, that behaviour doesn't happen with the `file` command.

If you want to read more, the [`xdg-mime` details are here](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-utils/tree/scripts/xdg-mime.in#n583) -- source  code. You can see that it calls `file` in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tel in 18.04 (more [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1049467/47206)):

```
xdg-mime query filetype YOURFILE
```

is the one that is reliable.

If you need the mime type to have a context menu action with some file manager like Nautilus or Dolphin, look in that file manager under the file's "Properties".

In Dolphin:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A short web-search with `google earth file format` gave the answer xdg-mime has the more precise answer, yet the 'z' most likely stands for a 'zipped' fileformat, so first is true too.