# Mime type for iso files in Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, 18.04, iso, dolphin, mime-type

***Posted in order to provide the answer.***

---

I have some desktop files for context menu actions (or service menus for Dolphin) to be applied to iso images (like mount/unmount). For example, the  Dolphin service [here](https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1214091/).

They used to work in the past but do not in Kubuntu 18.04.

Is there a problem with the mime-type maybe?

The line that worked was

```
MimeType=application/x-cd-image;application/x-raw-disk-image;
```

When I do

```
file --mime-type -b MY_ISO.iso
```

I get `application/x-iso9660-image`. Adding that to the `Mimetype` line: the context menu action is still absent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The needed mime type is:

```
model/x.stl-binary
```

To see the mime type that Dolphin sees for a file, right click the file, go to *Properties*, then *File type options*

[image]

Or use

```
xdg-mime query filetype YOURFILE
```

---

### But that was not a new feature, it was an error!

### **After re-installing the same system (for reasons that do not count here), all came back to normal.**